# How to get more than 4 people to show up under People and Places, using iOS16.2 on iPhone XR?

Tags: iphone, photos.app

When I open Photos on my iPhone XR running iOS 16.2, photos of only four people show up under People and Places on the Albums front page. Clicking on the word "People" in smaller type underneath them brings me to a list of eight, which I can then rearrange if I wish so that a different four occupy the top spots. But how can I show more than four photos under People and Places on the Albums front page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible to change. Each folder of albums is a 2×2 grid icon and the People folder acts the same.

You can provide Photos feedback at https://www.apple.com/feedback/photos/.